# sympy solve( ) with complex numbers

Tags: sympy, solver, complex-numbers

I have a hard time getting sympy to work with complex numbers.

Take the following example:

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol("x")

expr = sqrt(x)  # note that this is imaginary for x<0

# Find all solutions such that |expr| < 1

print( solve( abs(expr)<1, x ) )
```

This, however, only finds 0<=x<1.
It misses the negative x region -1<x.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Since `abs(sqrt(x)) = sqrt(x**2)` for real numbers, you could solve `sqrt(x**2)<1` instead.

```py
>>> solve(sqrt(x**2)<1)
(-1 < x) & (x < 1)
```

You can perhaps find the boundaries of the solution by replacing your argument of the `sqrt` with a negative or nonnegative symbol:

```py
>>> solve(abs(sqrt(n))-1)
[-1]
>>> var('nn',nonnegative=1)
nn
>>> solve(abs(sqrt(nn))-1)
[1]
```

Could you get the boundaries numerically?

```py
>>> [nsolve((abs(x**2+2*x-sqrt(x+5)))-1,i) for i in (-3,-1,0,1)]
[-2.86080585311170, 0.533751168755204, 0.533751168755204, 1.11490754147676]
```

Comment: well this works for my toy example but not for more general complex expressions. I have found no documentation on the fact that complex equations are not solved properly by Sympy.

Comment: Many forms of equations can be solved for complex solutions. But if you try to solve an equation like `abs(sqrt(x))-1` with `x` real it will tell you that the solver doesn't support solving `abs` with non-real arguments. When you try to solve it as an inequality, there are (apparently) other issues with solving an `abs` with `sqrt` as the argument. What's another form of equation that you think isn't supported over complex values?

Comment: I am basically trying to solve an inequality of type |expr| < 1, where expr is a sum over several terms, one of which is a square root. All the quantities that appear in expr are real numbers, but the term below the square root might be negative. The sympy solver does not warn me, it simply gives me the solutions for the case where the term below the root is positive.

Comment: I added some more suggestions.